# Simple Function to normalize related objects

Tags: r, function, relate

I'm quite new to R and I'm trying to write a function that normalizes my data in diffrent dataframes.

The normalization process is quite easy, I just divide the numbers I want to normalize by the population size for each object (that is stored in the table population). 
To know which object relates to one and another I tried to use IDs that are stored in each dataframe in the first column.

I thought to do so because some objects that are in the population dataframe have no corresponding objects in the dataframes to be normalized, as to say, the dataframes sometimes have lesser objects.

Normally one would built up a relational database (which I tried) but it didn't worked out for me that way. So I tried to related the objects within the function but the function didn't work. Maybe someone of you has experience with this and can help me.

so my attempt to  write this function was:

```
    # Load Tables
    # Agriculture, Annual Crops
    table.annual.crops <-read.table ("C:\\Users\\etc", header=T,sep=";")
    # Agriculture, Bianual and Perrenial Crops
    table.bianual.crops <-read.table ("C:\\Users\\etc", header=T,sep=";")
    # Fishery
    table.fishery <-read.table ("C:\\Users\\etc", header=T,sep=";")
    # Population per Municipality
    table.population <-read.table ("C:\\Users\\etc", header=T,sep=";")

    # attach data
    attach(table.annual.crops)
    attach(table.bianual.crops)
    attach(table.fishery)
    attach(table.population)


    # Create a function to normalize data
    # Objects should be related by their ID in the first column
    # Values to be normalized and the population appear in the second column
    funktion.norm.percapita<-function (x,y){if(x[,1]==y[,1]){x[,2]/y[,2]}else{return("0")}}

    # execute the function
    funktion.norm.percapita(table.annual.crops,table.population)
```

Comment: Could you please give us a sample of your dataset with head(dput(table.annual.crops))

Comment: @Chargaff:<br/>yes of course. I'm not quite sure how to create a table within the the comment but I think it will be understandable like this.so first the data with the population header(|Geocode||Population|) line1(|12345||3200|) line2(|12346|5320|) etc...and the other table with the data looks like this: header(|Geocode||CropValue|)line1(|12345||20,000|)line2(|12346||40,000|) etc.

Comment: Have you tried `merge` function? This will create a one data frame with the whole data. If you use merge, non existing values will be dropped from the final set. If you think that it will help then please first see this http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/merge.html

Comment: @user1785401 You can edit your post to include the output of dput. Also, you have to be careful with the use of attach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets start with the attach steps... why?  Its usually unecessary and can get you into trouble! Especially since both your population data.frame and your crops data.frame have Geocode as a column!

as suggested in the comments, you can use `merge`.  This will by default combine data.frames using columns of the same name.  You can specify which columns on which to merge with the `by` parameters.

```
dat <- merge(table.annual.crops, table.population)
dat$crop.norm <- dat$CropValue / dat$Population
```

The reason your function isn't working?  Look at the results of your `if` statemnt.

```
table.annual.crops[,1] == table.population[,1]
```

Gives a vector of booleans that will recycle the shorter vector.  If your data is quite large (on the order of millions of rows) the `merge` function can be slow.  if this is the case, take a look at the `data.table` package and use its merge function instead.

Comment: The merge function seems to work just fine. Without a second opinion it'S sometimes hard to see the "obvious". so, thank you very much for the explanations.